Django/Docker multiple containers error - could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
I am working on creating directory and subdirectories: main project directory that contains backend and frontend code/containers. I am working on the connection of main directory and the backend first.
Here's my backend docker-compose.yml:
`services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      # - ./docker/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    # volumes:
    #   - ./data:/app/backend/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  backend:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/app/backend
    env_file:
      - docker/environment/db.env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db

Here's my backend Dockerfile:
>! `FROM python:3
>! ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
>! ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
>! WORKDIR /app/backend/
>! COPY requirements.txt /app/backend/
>! RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
>! COPY . /app/backend/
>! EXPOSE 8000
>! CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]`
>! 
>! 
>! Also, here's the database settings in settings.py:
>! `DATABASES = {
>!     'default': {
>!         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
>!         'NAME': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_NAME'),
>!         'USER': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
>!         'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
>!         'HOST': 'db',
>!         'PORT': 5432,
>!     }
>! }`

My backend container works fine if I cd into backend and do a docker compose up.
I am trying to set up a docker-compose.yml from the main folder so that I can do a docker compose up from main directory and it would spin up the backend container (and later, the frontend container in the future).
Here's my docker-compose.yml for main:
`services:
  backend:
    build: ./backend 
    ports:
      - "8000:8000" 
    # networks:
    #   - "backend"   
    # networks:
    #   - backend
    # command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000  
    # volumes:
    #   - ./backend:/app/backend
    
    # restart: always
    # depends_on:
    #   - db
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: <ip address>

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: <ip address>/16`

Now if I do a docker compose up from main folder, I get the following error:
enter image description here
What am I missing?
Tried creating a network in the docker-compose.yml for main directory.

You seem to have included a link to an image in place of the error message; can you [edit] the question to include the error in plain text?  Your final Compose file doesn't seem to include the database container at all, should it?

[Update] I think I solved it.
I updated my docker-compose.yml in main folder to have a db service. Also added a db.env file so the backend service knows how to connect to db.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
